# fill 2 forms one time php

Tags: php, forms

I have one form like this

```
Arrivo:
<select name="arrivo">
<option value="2014-06-15">domenica 15 Giugno</option>
<option value="2014-06-16">lunedì 16 Giugno</option>
<option value="2014-06-17">martedì 17 Giugno</option>
Partenza:   <select name="partenza">
<option value="2014-06-15">domenica 15 Giugno</option>
<option value="2014-06-16">lunedì 16 Giugno</option>
<option value="2014-06-17">martedì 17 Giugno</option>
<option value="2014-06-18">mercoledì 18 Giugno</option>
Adulti:   
<select name="PER">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" VALUE = "Calcola Preventivo">
</form>
```

I need that some data (like ARRIVO E PARTENZA) will auto-filled in another form (that will be created after a user click on submit), that will be added a new field that user must complete. See this example (where name and email are the new field that user must fill in the second form)

```
Arrivo:
<input type="text" name="arrivo2" value='$_POST['arrivo']><br>
Partenza
<input type="text" name="partenza2" value='$_POST['partenza']><br>
email
<input type="text" name="email"><br>
Name
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" VALUE = "emailme">
```

Comment: you have to be a bit more clear... Please explain more

Comment: use jquery for this purpose

Comment: thanks..what jquery function?

Comment: you can try storing values in session variables and display it in another form

Comment: sorry I don't understand

Comment: i have posted the solution in answer.check it out.if have any query post a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**form 1**

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="hidden" name="hidname"/>
</form>
```

after submitting this form (i assume you know process for submitting a form) get the post values in session variable like this

```
session_start();// this starts a session
$_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['hidname']=$_POST['hidname'];
```

**from 2**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="name2" value="<?php  if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) echo $_SESSION['name'];?>"/>
<input type="text" name="hidname2" value="<?php  if(isset($_SESSION['hidname'])) echo $_SESSION['hidname'];?>" />
</form>
```